# Nodejs & aws-sdk: Simultaneous access to multiple regions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ses

Currently setup my S3 access in Node using:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.region       = 'us-west-1';
AWS.config.credentials  = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'default'});
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
```

Now I would also like access to SES. Unfortunately, SES does not exist on us-west-1, so I had to setup SES on a different region.

How can I proceed? If I alter AWS.config, will that affect my previously instantiated s3?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured out that there are other ways to specify the region. This seems to do the trick:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.SharedIniFileCredentials({profile: 'default'});
var s3  = new AWS.S3({region:'us-west-1'});
var ses = new AWS.SES({region:'us-west-2'});
```

Comment: why is it `SES` ? and not another `new AWS.S3`?

Comment: In my case I was trying to use SES in one region and S3 in another region... I assume doing two S3 instances in two different regions would work as well.